# Conversion from Qstring to std::string throws an exception

Tags: c++, qt4

Surprisingly the below code is throwing an exception.

```
QString qtemp = QDir::tempPath(); 
std::string temp = qtemp.toStdString();  
std::cout<<temp<<std::endl;
```

When I debugged using visual studio - I go the value for the variable `qtemp` . But in the next step I get a BAD Pointer from the debugger which results in an exception when I cout the same.

Comment: Can you post a complete, compilable program that reproduces this (maybe even include the .pro file)?  If I drop those lines in `main()` function with the appropriate `#include`s added, I don't see a problem.

Comment: If the path has unicode characters then this code can be problematic.

Comment: @ Michael Burr - Unfortunately , this is a small part of my program and giving a .pro file would not be ideal. However I tried out by commenting every other line  in the program and still the same problem remains.
@wilhelmtell - what would be the solution?

Comment: Use `.toStdWString()` and `std::wstring` instead.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known symptom if you're mixing debug and release DLLs.

Comment: you sir saved me a lot of trouble